# Order within order

Tags: knowledge, sequence

Here's a little sequence of letters & numbers arranged in a specific way. Without yet giving away anymore info other than the title, the tag and that this sequence is *complete* try replace the question marks.

**D11010101Z, ━━━━, A1011101F, A111101U, A101100011L, A1-100001100G, ????????**

Comment: I've been tearing my hair out for hours now and I can't make headway. Is it too early to ask for a small hint?

Comment: @Sciborg I think Amos got this. I'll wait and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like

> A110110R

I got stuck on the 'order within an order'; thanks OP for the hint!

> If one orders the seven continents alphabetically and within that orders their countries alphabetically, this sequence is the first country from each continent.   (scrambled as described in a little bit)
>  Africa - Algeria
>  Antarctica - Antarctica, not a country I guess, so an M-dash
>  Asia - Afghanistan
>  Australia - Australia
>  Europe - Albania
>  N America - Antigua/Barbuda
>  and the missing entry, S America - Argentina
>  Each result is then scrambled as such:
>  Numeric country code converted to binary, nested within the 2 digit ISO code.
>  Argentina is country code 54=110110 binary, ISO Code 'AR' yields: A110110R

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you got to this? If you have figured out something it may be helpful to explain for others to work on.

Comment: @Amos Zoellner You basically got it. rot13(gur svefg ragel yvrf va? gur frpbaq va? gur guveq, sbhegu rgp va? ...naq Jul?)

Comment: To reviewers: Obviously this answer needs to be explained, but it's not worth deleting, especially since the OP has said "You basically got it."

Comment: The explanation does need to be [edit]ed into the answer, though ...

Comment: Updated with explanation